# Dependencies between two Django projects

Tags: python, django, import, reference, dependencies

I have a question concerning dependencies between two Django projects.

I have two Django Projects, P1 and P2. I want to import a form model from **P2 > apps > app1 > forms > form.py**. I marked P1 as depending on P2 (using Pycharm) and tried to use **from app1.forms import form.py** inside my model.py file of an app in P1. PyCharm now says that app1 is an unresolved reference. Is there any step I missed?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you add P2 to your [python path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)?

Comment: I thought that was what PyCharm does when setting P1 as depending on P2, but now I realized, that therefor I have to mark apps as a root folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm adds only source folders automatically to the python path. So I marked app1 as a source folder and everything works.